# Webstorm: what does "excluded" really mean, regarding project subdirectories?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

In Webstorm, project subdirectories can be marked as "excluded". What are the full consequences of this flag? The Webstorm documentation stays quite vague about this. Does it affect debugging or deployment?

Many thanks for your explanations.

EDIT:

They say: "Excluded folders are not involved in indexing and therefore they are ignored while searching, parsing, watching etc." .

1. Why 'watching' - my gulp script does the watching ... .
2. And what is meant by 'etc' - more consequences ?

Comment: It won't kill your memory and performance while searching or using completion features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will exclude these directories from search and indexing.

Comment: That is what I would expect anyway. But does it influence more?

Comment: If you are talking about influence to other programs (like LESS watcher outside IDE or GIT) than no. All it does is inside IDE configs set flags to exclude these files from inner-tasks.

Comment: I especially mean influence on debugging, which involves sourcemaps, and, in my case, webpack.